# SVG image from org-babel

Tags: latex, org-babel, images

I am trying to create a SVG image from latex code in an org-mode file.

```
#+name: foo
#+header: :file foo.svg
#+begin_src latex
bar
#+end_src
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
executing Latex code block (foo)...
org-babel-execute:latex: HTML file produced but SVG file requested
```

On the `Shell Command Output` buffer the following error seems relevant, but I am not able to determine what is causing it.

```
[...]
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)) (./latex-Mz7Vfn.aux)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: Tightpage 0 0 0 0
[1]
! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 

l.7 ...e{amsmath}\begin{document}bar\end{document}

? 
! Emergency stop.
\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 

l.7 ...e{amsmath}\begin{document}bar\end{document}

Output written on latex-Mz7Vfn.dvi (1 page, 2384 bytes).
Transcript written on latex-Mz7Vfn.log.
[...]
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but my interpretation of the error message is that it doesn't like the idea of `\end{document}` inside `amsmath` environment. Maybe specifying `:file` also requires `:results` of some sort?  So that LaTeX source for the file wouldn't be inserted verbatim into the generated LaTeX file?

Comment: @wvxvw There is no `amsmath` environment involved here. The last command of the LaTeX header is just `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: @Tobias oh, I see, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latex body `bar` does not define a tikz-image that could be exported as svg.

Therefore you only get a html file. That is exactly what the error message

> ```
> executing Latex code block (foo)...
> org-babel-execute:latex: HTML file produced but SVG file requested
> ```

says.

Instead of your example org file with latex body `bar` try the following org file containing a tikz image 
(it is adapted from the accepted solution of the question ["Using TikZ for a simple drawing" on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51214/44136)).

```
#+name: foo
#+header: :file foo.svg :headers \usetikzlibrary{positioning}\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
#+begin_src latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45,font=\sffamily]
    \node (X) at (0,0) {x};
    \node (Y) [below left=2cm and 1cm of X]  {y};% 2cm below, 1cm to the left (optional)
    \node (Z) [below right=2cm and 1cm of X] {z};
    \node (U) [below left=2cm and 1cm of Z]  {u};
    \draw [semithick,->] (X) -- (Y);
    \draw [semithick,->] (X) -- (Z);
    \draw [semithick,->] (Y) -- (U) node [midway,below,sloped] {*};
    \draw [semithick,->] (Z) -- (U) node [midway,below,sloped] {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

Note that I use pstricks instead of tikz in LaTeX documents. For that reason I had to resort to the example I found on tex.se and could not easily produce an example with the string `bar` as tikz image.